# How to get the computer's name running OSX from its IP

Tags: mac-osx, hostname

Some computer is doing some large data transfer on the office network, which we could only get the IP address. We know that it is running OSX, but we do not know its computer name so we do not know which computer it is. Are there any easy way to the name of the computer running OSX?

Answer (score -1):

The following command works in OSX:

```
dig @224.0.0.251 -p5353 -x whatever.ip.you.want
```

Comment: Raymond, instead of just pasting a command can you explain what is going on here and why it would work? What is special about this command? References to manpages and other high quality sources are helpful.

Comment: @RaymondTau This isn't really a great answer - your solution only works if (a) your DNS server happens to be `224.0.0.251` (multicast used by Bonjour), (b) your DNS server happens to be listening on port 5353 (also used by Bonjour, but not in all environments), and (c) you happen to have reverse DNS entries available for the IP in question.  (a) and (b) are not true in my environment (in fact they're probably not true anywhere except YOUR environment), and (c) is very often not true in small office environment.